# Make std::unique<T> compatible with std::unique<const T, CustomDeleterType>

Tags: c++, c++11

In the code I have 3 std::unique_ptr pointer types defined for a particular object:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<MyObject> nonConstPtrDefaultDelete;

typedef std::unique_ptr<MyObject, std::function<void(MyObject *)>>
                                                       nonConstPtrCustomDelete;

typedef std::unique_ptr<const MyObject, std::function<void(const MyObject *)>>
                                                       ConstPtrCustomDelete;
```

I ran into a use case where I need to a convert nonConstPtrDefaultDelete into ConstPtrCustomDelete and nonConstPtrCustomDelete into ConstPtrCustomDelete.
In other words:

```
nonConstPtrDefaultDelete a;
nonConstPtrCustomDelete b;

ConstPtrCustomDelete c1(a);  // Compiler error Deleter has incompatible type
ConstPtrCustomDelete c2(b);  // Compiler error Deleter has incompatible type
```

The main problem comes from incompatibility of types signature for the deleting functions. It is possible to fix the nonConstPtrCustomDelete case by changing the definition of nonConstPtrCustomDelete type in the following way:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<MyObject, std::function<void(const MyObject *)>>
                                                         nonConstPtrCustomDelete
```

However, the most frequent case with DefaultDelete is still producing compilation error, despite it is intuitively clear that conversion is possible.
It there a way workaround that limitation and hint the compiler that functions are castable from one into another?

Thank you

Comment: +1 Good question. If the templated move constructor can't handle this, what can it handle, i.e. what's it for? I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh. A function `void(T*)` is not convertible to `void(T const*)`. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Do you really need to use `std::function` for the deleter? Do different `unique_ptr` instances use different functions for the deleter, or do they all use the same type of deleter? If the latter, it would be easier to create a custom deleter object that does the right thing, instead of storing something in `std::function`. Then you could add conversions between your custom deleter types, which you can't do for `std::function`

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure that deleter is proper you can convert DefaultDelete to your type:

```
nonConstPtrDefaultDelete a;
ConstPtrCustomDelete c1( a.release(), your_deleter );
```

same with const/non const version. But why you need 2 versions (one for const and 1 for not) is not clear.

Answer (score 4):

The example given,

```
nonConstPtrDefaultDelete a;
nonConstPtrCustomDelete b;

ConstPtrCustomDelete c1(a);  // Compiler error Deleter has incompatible type
ConstPtrCustomDelete c2(b);  // Compiler error Deleter has incompatible type
```

… has two problems:

- You can't construct a `unique_ptr` from an lvalue expression. It's single ownership, but the lvalue expression asks for a copy.
- For the deleter, that a function type `void(T*)` is not compatible with a function type `void(T const*)`.

A `void(T const*)` deleter function is necessary when the pointer type is `T const*`, and works nicely also when the pointer type is `T*`. So, disregarding established practice, it would be the most practical convention. However, at one time, before the first standardization of C++, deletion via a `T const*` was considered so unnatural (and the changing const-ness of an object during construction and destruction was so not well understood) that `delete p;` for such a pointer was invalid.

For the first problem, the common solution is to use `std::move` from the `<utility>` header:

```
ConstPtrCustomDelete c1( move( a ) );
ConstPtrCustomDelete c2( move( b ) );
```

For the second problem one solution is to outfit every `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter such as an instance of `std::default_delete<T const>`.

Another solution is to use a more accepting deleter type in the cases where you want a custom deleter, namely one that <sup>1</sup>handles `const`-ness:

```
template< class Type >
class Deleter
{
private:
    function<void(Type const*)> d_;

public:
    using Mutable_type = typename remove_const<Type>::type;

    void operator()( Type const* p ) const
    {
        d_( p );
    }

    Deleter(): d_( default_delete<Type const>() ) {}

    Deleter( default_delete<Mutable_type> const& )
        : d_( default_delete<Type const>() )
    {}

    template< class D >
    Deleter( D const& d )
        : d_( [d]( Type const* p ) {
            d( const_cast<Mutable_type*>( p ) );
            } )
    {}
};
```

Your example code with `move` and with such a custom deleter, is then

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<MyObject> nonConstPtrDefaultDelete;

typedef std::unique_ptr<MyObject, Deleter<MyObject>>
    nonConstPtrCustomDelete;

typedef std::unique_ptr<const MyObject, Deleter<MyObject const>>
    ConstPtrCustomDelete;

nonConstPtrDefaultDelete a;
nonConstPtrCustomDelete b;

ConstPtrCustomDelete c1( move( a ) );
ConstPtrCustomDelete c2( move( b ) );
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> There is a potential problem with the `const_cast` for a rare case, namely formal UB when the object is originally `const` and the deleter function `d` calls some non-`const` member function before the destructor. That can be solved by making this conversion support an explicit choice via template parameter. I.e. client code explicitly guaranteeing an ordinary well-behaved function.</sub>

Comment: Because `operator()` accepts `Type const*`, couldn't you just use `Deleter<MyObject>` for both `const` and non-`const` cases (lose the converting constructor template) ?  Or maybe it is still needed to allow conversion from the default deleter type.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, the convering constructor is used for converting `std::default_delete<MyObject>`. And it also handles the case of an arbitrary deleter function, which the OP indicates is needed by using `std::function`. I'm not sure how general this is, it's just off-the-cuff code (compiled with g++ and Visual C++).

Comment: Ick, you cast away const!  If the data was originally const, say `std::make_unique<const T>()`, I believe that is undefined behavior to call ... basically anything on it as a non-const `T*`.  In practice, this may not be a problem, so long as you have moderate amounts of luck.  It would be cleaner/safer/sufficient to just make your `Deleter` take a `default_delete<T>` and store a `default_delete<const T>` instead of that `const_cast`.

Comment: @Yakk: The destructor is a non-`const` member function.  There is no issue. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That is a reasonable argument, but not a convincing one.  [Hmm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/237ef4d02d478905).  Going further, expr.const.cast leads to dcl.type.cv which leads to basic.life which leads to "modify" (whose definition I cannot find).  I am unsure if `delete t;` causes `*t` to be "modified" prior to the lifetime of `t` ending with `t` of pointer to non-const type.  But that gets silly.  Regardless, there is a definite danger if you had a cleanup function that didn't just call delete.

Comment: @Yakk: The formal lifetime ends when the call of the destructor of the most derived type starts. That's in order to allow destructors to modify, similarly to how constructors modify before the formal lifetime starts. It's very symmetric. Your point would have stood in pre-standard (ARM) C++. But then, at that time there was no problem that required such solution. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Aha, lifetime ends at the start of the dtor.  So anything that happens inside the dtor isn't a problem.  Logically, `delete t;` does not modify `*t`.  Still, it breaks if you have a cleanup function that actually expect a non-const `T` and operates on it in ways besides `delete t;`...

Comment: [undefined behavior](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbd5447e9e2d5813) -- I just modified a `const foo`.  The cleanup code differs between const and non-const implementations, and your code dispatched the const case to the non-const case.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes one can create UB by having the cleanup call something before the destructor. I think that's a good point, thanks! If there is some easy solution to that (considering that most every cleanup function takes pointer to non-`const`) I'd like to apply it. Maybe one can test if the cleanup function *can* be called with pointer to `const`? I'm only getting pictures of spaghetti TMP code here. :(

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid. It should just be an explicit choice, a template parameter. I think. Later…

Comment: `Deleter( std::default_delete<Type> const&):Deleter( std::default_delete<const Type>{} ){}`, then do away with `const_cast` in `D const&` implementation.  We know that the case with default delete we can safely ignore the lack of const, we don't know in general, so solve that problem.

Comment: @Yakk: Thanks! It matters for the case where `default_delete` is specialized for a type. Fixing.

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem:

```
template<class T>
using smarter_default_delete = std::default_delete<const T>;

template<class T, class D=smarter_default_delete<T>>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, D>;

typedef my_unique_ptr<MyObject> nonConstPtrDefaultDelete;
```

basically, `default_delete` doesn't accept `T const*`s.  The above fixes that.

You could also jump through hoops on the other two types to force the conversion to work.  But the above looks easier.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `std::function` here?

Do you actually need different instances of `nonConstPtrCustomDelete` to have different deleters that share the same signature, or do all instances use the same deleter?

i.e. do you ever do this:

```
void foo_deleter(MyObject*);
void bar_deleter(MyObject*);

nonConstPtrCustomDelete ptr1{ foo(), foo_deleter };
nonConstPtrCustomDelete ptr1{ bar(), bar_deleter };
```

or only this:

```
nonConstPtrCustomDelete ptr1{ foo(), foo_deleter };
nonConstPtrCustomDelete ptr1{ bar(), foo_deleter };
```

If only the latter then using `std::function` is pointless, and inefficient. You don't need a polymorphic type-erased function object if you always use the same deleter.

Instead you should write a custom deleter type:

```
struct non_const_deleter {
  void operator()(MyObject*) const;
};
```

Then your typedef can be:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<MyObject, non_const_deleter>
   nonConstPtrCustomDelete;
```

it's also easier to use, because that deleter can be default-constructed and so you don't need to provide it explicitly:

```
nonConstPtrCustomDelete ptr1{ foo() };
```

that is exactly equivalent to:

```
nonConstPtrCustomDelete ptr1{ foo(), non_const_deleter{} };
```

Now you could either add a second deleter type that a `non_const_deleter` can convert to:

```
struct const_deleter {
  const_deleter() = default;
  const_deleter(const non_const_deleter&) { }
  void operator()(const MyObject*) const;
};
```

or maybe just make the one type handle both cases:

```
struct const_and_non_const_deleter {
  void operator()(MyObject*) const;
  void operator()(const MyObject*) const;
};
```

Then both types can use the same deleter:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<MyObject, const_and_non_const_deleter>
   nonConstPtrCustomDelete;
typedef std::unique_ptr<const MyObject, const_and_non_const_deleter>
   constPtrCustomDelete;
```

and you won't have problems converting nonConstPtr to constPtr.